# Is it okay to use the !important in this case?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make a calculator to apply what I learned recently about Javascript, this code works, the calculator looks nice but I had to use the !important property. Does that come with any risk? Is it a good method? Since I am a beginner I am not sure if the new information and shortcuts that I find online to make stuff easier to do, are actually good. Here is my entire code:

```js
function calcNumbers(result) {
  form.displayResult.value = form.displayResult.value + result;
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  background: rgba(155, 70, 194, 0.479);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #E69A8DFF;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 320px;
}

.display {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  background: #7FFFD4;
  border-top-left-radius: 14px;
  border-top-right-radius: 14px;
}

.buttons {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}

.row {
  width: 280px;
  float: left;
}

input[type=button] {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ecedef;
  border: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #5E5858;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 270px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0 25px;
}

.red {
  background: #ffffff !important;
  color: #490050 !important;
}

.green {
  background: #400164 !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form name="form" id="myForm">
    <div class="display">
      <input type="text" placeholder="0" name="displayResult" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="C" class="red">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="button" name="b7" value="7" onClick="calcNumbers(b7.value)">
      <input type="button" name="b8" value="8" onClick="calcNumbers(b8.value)">
      <input type="button" name="b9" value="9" onClick="calcNumbers(b9.value)">
      <input type="button" name="addb" value="+" onClick="calcNumbers(addb.value)">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="button" name="b4" value="4" onClick="calcNumbers(b4.value)">
      <input type="button" name="b5" value="5" onClick="calcNumbers(b5.value)">
      <input type="button" name="b6" value="6" onClick="calcNumbers(b6.value)">
      <input type="button" name="subb" value="-" onClick="calcNumbers(subb.value)">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="button" name="b1" value="1" onClick="calcNumbers(b1.value)">
      <input type="button" name="b2" value="2" onClick="calcNumbers(b2.value)">
      <input type="button" name="b3" value="3" onClick="calcNumbers(b3.value)">
      <input type="button" name="mulb" value="*" onClick="calcNumbers(mulb.value)">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="button" name="b0" value="0" onClick="calcNumbers(b0.value)">
      <input type="button" name="potb" value="." onClick="calcNumbers(potb.value)">
      <input type="button" name="divb" value="/" onClick="calcNumbers(divb.value)">
      <input type="button" class="green" value="=" onClick="displayResult.value=eval(displayResult.value)">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do both your `.red` and `.green` classes make things **violet**?

Comment: Short answer: `!important` is okay **when there is no acceptable way to avoid it**, and only then.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there's just no way around the !important operator (mostly when working with third party css files you want to override).

However, in your case you should be able to override styles just by making the selector more specific than others.

In your code you could change `.red` with `input[type=button].red`, that would make it more specific and thus it would override it! (That's the cascading part of Cascading Style Sheets).

Comment: Deleted my answer s it was the same as this :)

Comment: `input.red` is sufficient. **Never** make a selector more specific than necessary.

Comment: Your statement is right, only looking at his markup he probably just wants to set the color of the button and not of any other inputs :)

Answer (score 0):

Question for you: I don't see where those classes are being implemented -- are you using them? `!important` is used to override any existing properties of the element it's applied to, so you can use it to emphasize that you want this property to take priority always. There's nothing inherently bad about using it, though it's considered bad practice to overuse them (probably not an issue in your case). Also, note where you have them and keep that in mind in case you apply some styling that you can see in the future. The `!important` will override *everything*. Good luck on you project.

Comment: Look harder :) The input with `value="C"` had red

Answer (score 0):

A bit of background about why you may have needed `!important` in the first place.  It comes down to 'specificity', you can read more about the rules here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

*Normally* `!important` can lead to a *smell* that your CSS isn't very well structured, and you should often be able to get the desired results with well defined CSS taking into account the rules of specificity.  Once you start using `!important` when it's not really needed, you end up using it more places to override other `!important` styles, which is bad.

For the likes of a `.red` class, I would say thats a case where it *may* make sense to use `!important` as it feels like a CSS class that if it were applied, it *should* render something red, i.e. it is a class of high importance and wouldn't make sense to have a class of `red` assigned to an element, but that doesn't render red text, or whatever the class is designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you think `!important` is required is that you are trying to change CSS properties (`background-color` and `color`) which have already been defined using this selector:

```
input[type=text]
```

Because this selector consists of an element selector `input` **and** and attribute selector `[type=text]`, its [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) beats that of a simple `.green` CSS class. Understanding specificity is the groundwork for using CSS. There's no way around understanding that concept.

To avoid having to use `!important`, simply raise the selectors to the same level of specificity as what already is there:

```
input.green
```

and

```
input.red
```

That being said, both `.red` and `.green` are really, I mean, ***really*** bad choices for CSS class names. CSS class names should never contain information about a specific styling of any elements, but instead describe what the CSS class does functionally.

The reason for this is when your customer comes next week and wants blue instead of green buttons, you will either also have to change the HTML (which is almost always unwanted, and, with proper class names, also almost always unnecessary), or start doing what you did, which is keep using color names in the CSS and HTML that actually do not represent the color their names claim to represent.